# Toggle Switch to swap the connections of two buttons

Tags: switches

I am trying to mod my arcade stick so I can switch two commonly swapped buttons on the controller.

Essentially they are simple 2 terminal momentary switches connected directly to the controller PCB. I would like to switch their responsibilities, so in my case the Back button and the LB button on the XBox pcb I would like to swap so the Back actuates the LB button on the PCB and the LB actuates the Back button.

My assumption is that I would need a switch with 8 terminals, 4 in 4 out.

What type of switch am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two existing buttons do not share a common GND connection then you will need a four pole double pole (4PDT) toggle switch. Such switch has twelve terminals.

If the two existing buttons share a common GND then you can get by with a double pole double throw (DPDT) switch. That switch will have six terminals.

Here is how you would connect the button flipper switch when a common GND is in place.

[image]

If the two switches do not share a common GND then you would use the 4PDT switch and basically duplicate the above circuit on the switch for the other sides of each button.

Comment: I am actually unsure whether they share a common ground. The PCB is housed in a closed off compartment so I'll see if I can open that and check the GND. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: If you have easy access to the two push button's terminals then it is easy to check for a common connection between them using a multimeter on the OHMS scale or the CONTINUITY test scale.